# What are covert channel algorithms?

Tags: terminology, algorithm

*Covert channels* are normally used for communicating illegally or for some hidden communications, but I am trying to figure out what *covert channel algorithms* might be.

Has anyone heard of this term before and what does it mean?

How covert channel algorithms could be implemented in non-Computing environments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Covert channel algorithms* is most commonly used as a name given to a set of algorithms used in [IDS/IPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) (Intrusion Detection/Prevention Systems) to detect, analyze and identify covert channels in TCP/IP networks, for example by probabilistic statistical analysis by e.g. using the [Markov model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_model) TCP packet analysis, [Bayesian inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) and other *algorithms*, deterministic by static traffic analysis, rule set matching, or by several other techniques / algorithms that might be in place with various intrusion detection systems.

Suggested further reading:

- [Network Covert Channels: Design, Analysis, Detection, and Elimination](https://spaf.cerias.purdue.edu/Students/cabuk_thesis.pdf) (Serdar Cabuk, Purdue University - PDF)
- [Covert channels analysis in TCP/IP networks](https://web.archive.org/web/20200113201829/http://gray-world.net:80/papers/ALLIX_Covert_Channels_analysis_in_TPC_IP_networks.pdf) (Pierre Allix, IFIPS School of Engineering
  University of Paris­-Sud XI, Orsay, France - PDF)
- [A Covert Channel Detection Algorithm Based on TCP Markov Model](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5671231) (Jiangtao Zhai ; Sch. of Autom., Nanjing Univ. of Sci. & Technol., Nanjing, China ; Guangjie Liu ; Yuewei Dai)
- [A Robust Network Covert Channel Algorithm Based on Spread Coding](https://caod.oriprobe.com/articles/32086765/A_Robust_Network_Covert_Channel_Algorithm_Based_on_Spread_Coding.htm) (NIU Xiaopeng*, LI Qingbao, WANG Zuo)
- [An Approach to Analyze Covert Channel Based on Finite State Machine](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5671025/?arnumber=5671025&punumber=5669394&sortType=asc_p_Sequence&filter=AND%28p_IS_Number:5670801%29&pageNumber=5) (Xiong Liu ; Dept. of Comput. Sci. & Technol., Tsinghua Univ., Beijing, China ; Jian-guo Hao ; Yi-qi Dai)

Comment: thanks for your help :) , in fact i needed a start up i wasn't able to figure it out what it could be... a detection algos or what....

Comment: @ame - No thanks needed, I'm glad to have helped. It is however customary to mark a helpful answer as such throughout [SE], so others having similar questions and will find yours know which answer to trust. ;)

Comment: oh yes but my repo is not 15 :( as just my 1st post....

Comment: @ame - I meant the checkmark under the vote buttons. I mean... if it answered your question. ;)